# Core Plot not displaying labels (but it displays the graph and axes fine)

Tags: macos, core-plot, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to draw a graph on my OS X app and I've successfully drawn the graph and the axes:

[image]

The data (looking at the trend) and the y-axis ticks seem to be normal. But as seen above, there are no labels on either axes and there are also no ticks at the X axis.

Here is my code:

```
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.mainGraph.bounds];
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 50;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 60;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 10;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 16;
self.mainGraph.hostedGraph = graph;
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace*)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterNoStyle;
NSTimeInterval oneDay = 60 * 60 * 24;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
CPTTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[CPTTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
timeFormatter.multiplier = @(oneDay);

NSDate *refDate = [graphDates firstObject];
timeFormatter.referenceDate = refDate;
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (id)graph.axisSet;
CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor grayColor];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;

axisSet.yAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0];
axisSet.yAxis.title = @"Followers";
axisSet.yAxis.titleOffset = 0;
axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInt(1000);
axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 9;
axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 4;
axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength = 10;
axisSet.yAxis.tickDirection = CPTSignNone;
axisSet.yAxis.labelFormatter = numberFormatter;

axisSet.xAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0];
axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInt(oneDay * 7);
axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 6;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.labelFormatter = timeFormatter;
axisSet.xAxis.labelRotation = M_PI / 4;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 10;
```

I've also tried assigning labeling policies, but no avail (best I could get was also losing my Y-axis ticks too).

And on data refresh (including the initial load), after this code:

```
graphMax = followers * 1.1;
graphMin = 0;
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace*)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
NSTimeInterval intervalSpan = [[graphDates lastObject] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - [[graphDates firstObject] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(intervalSpan)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(graphMin) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(graphMax)];
```

Where `graphDates` hold the smallest and the biggest date in a sorted order, which is a few days back and just now respectively in my case.

My graph and my plot area frame have a lot of padding at all sides, so it doesn't seem to be the common padding issue. What else causes labels not to display?

Comment: What are `numberFormatter` and `timeFormatter`? Are they non-null at this point in the code? What is the `xRange` of the plot space? What is `oneDay`?

Comment: @EricSkroch I've updated the cide.

Comment: What is the `xRange` of the plot space? What version of OS X are you using? There are problems with labels on the El Capitan beta (see [issue 210](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/210)).

Comment: @EricSkroch I've updated the question with the ranges. and oops, exactly, I'm on El Capitan, though it's not a beta, it's the GM seed. but that's probably it! I'm not really sure about the xRange ticks drawing though.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your data, but it appears the `intervalSpan` is less than `oneDay`. That would put the first tick mark on the x-axis off screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was specific to El Capitan and Core Plot and it was addressed by the framework.